# Immutability with Recods vs. Classes with auto-implemented get-only properties

Tags: c#, immutability, record

Is there any difference regarding **immutablity** when using classes with auto-implemented get-only properties versus a C# 9 record? I imagine compiler does backing fields(?) and magic under the hood to support the syntactic sugar, however say types below were data transfer objects, are they immutable once deserialized? Apart from the shorter syntax, is there any immutability enhancement of the record vs the class?

For instance

```cs
public class RgbColor 
{
    public RgbColor(int r, int g, int b) { /* do assign here ... */ }
    public int Red { get; }
    public int Green { get; }
    public int Blue { get; }
}
```

versus

```cs
public record RgbColor (
   int Red,
   int Green,
   int Blue
);
```

Comment: There is no magic deep-copy immutability bestowed on properties just because they're part of a record, no. Of course, if you want that, a good idea is to make all of the types involved records.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record):

> You can create record types with immutable properties by using positional parameters or standard property syntax:
>
> ```
> public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
> ```

And:

> You can also create record types with mutable properties and fields:
>
> ```
> public record Person
> {
>     public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
>     public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;
> };
> ```

This is equally mutable as your class.